# Oracle Apex Images not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: oracle, internet-explorer, apex

I'm using a Display Image Item with settings section set to 'BLOB Column returned by SQL statement'.

It shows the image (are big sized) without problems in Chrome, Edge or firefox but on IE it only shows a little black square with an X inside.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: which version of APEX are you using ? by the way, have you tried on Edge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for IE is deprecated since version 20.2, and even before there were features that did not work properly. My advice: don't use IE with Apex, if you can, use always other browsers which are properly supported and work without issues.

Display images might be one of those issues. Starting with Apex 18 this might be due to a problem with IE11 when using the `X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff` response HTTP header. The images from the display image items are not displayed correctly in IE11 because Apex is not able to define the correct mimetype.

This is reproducible in the case of BLOB Column Return by SQL Statement, which is exactly your case. You can confirm it using the console debug mode.

**Notes**

> 6.1.4 Support for Internet Explorer 11: Deprecated Support for Internet Explorer (IE) 11 is deprecated.
>
> Starting with release 20.2, only the current and prior major release
> of Microsoft Edge along with Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Apple
> Safari will be supported.

Deprecated means you can still use it, but support will ultimately be removed for it. Also as Microsoft has removed IE as its standard browser, replacing it by Edge, it is likely you will always have unexpected behaviour in this browser.

We all know that for security reasons and compatibility with legacy applications, many companies still use IE in order for those applications to work properly. However, using it with Oracle Apex is always a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks i've checked with debug mode and you are right.

Comment: @IgnasiS, you are very welcome ;)